# JSON_QUERY(@data, '$') get only the first element from JSON

Tags: .net, sql-server, json-query

I have multirow JSON generated from MSSQL with WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER:

```
{
 "fName":"John",
 "lName":"Smith"
},
{
 "fName":"Emma",
 "lName":"Watson"
},
{
 "fName":"Harry",
 "lName":"Potter"
}
```

Next in stored procedure I'm building the response with:

```
select json_query(@data, '$') as data,
@status as status,
@responseMessage as message
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

But by this way in data I'm getting only the first element:

```
{
 "data":{
  "fName":"John",
  "lName":"Smith"
 }
}
```

When I extract the data in first JSON without using WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER its OK, but my .NET app getting exception with empty result and HTTP 500.

My .NET code:

```
    response = await new SQLDataContext().StoredProcedureExecuteReaderAsync<SQLDataResult>("SP_name", parameters);


    public class SQLDataResult
    {
        public SQLDataResult()
        {
            // Status = SQLDataResultStatus.Error;
            status = -1;
            message = "An error occured";
        }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        // public SQLDataResultStatus Status;
        public int status;

        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string message;

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public dynamic data;
    }
```

Comment: Since the data in your first json is an array have you tried to add square brackets around it?

Comment: Yes. I have tried like I say - without using WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER its OK, but my .NET app getting exception with empty result and HTTP 500.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do it WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, I'd leave that in there and just get the first index through C# instead. Something like this:

```
var response = (await new SQLDataContext().StoredProcedureExecuteReaderAsync<List<SQLDataResult>>("SP_name", parameters))[0];
```